# Adding a list to a nested list in Scala

Tags: list, scala, nested-lists

I am trying to add a list to a nested list.
Given I have the following:

```
List[["Bob","Mike","Sam"],["Aims","Rose","Katie"]]
```

How can I add this:

```
List["Max","Paul","Alex"]
```

So that it results in this:

```
List[["Bob","Mike","Sam"],["Aims","Rose","Katie"],["Max","Paul","Alex"]]
```

Comment: Your lists are not legal Scala code.

Comment: As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `:++ [B >: A](suffix: IterableOnce[B]): CC[B]` method

```
List(List("Bob","Mike","Sam"),List("Aims","Rose","Katie")).:++(List(List("Max","Paul","Alex")))
```

result:

```
List(List("Bob","Mike","Sam"),List("Aims","Rose","Katie"),List("Max","Paul","Alex"))
```

or

use `:: [B >: A](elem: B): List[B]` method

```
List(List("Bob","Mike","Sam"),List("Aims","Rose","Katie"))::List(List("Max","Paul","Alex"))
```

or `:+ [B >: A](elem: B)`

```
List(List("Bob","Mike","Sam"),List("Aims","Rose","Katie")).:+(List("Max","Paul","Alex"))
```

or  `appended[B >: A](elem: B): CC[B]` method

```
List(List("Bob","Mike","Sam"),List("Aims","Rose","Katie")).appended(List("Max","Paul","Alex"))
```